# Multi-touch buttons on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, multi-touch

I am using bunch of rectangle shapes in my Windows Phone 8 app and I need to support multi-touch so a few of them can be tapped at one time. I am not doing any extra handling on this as I thought that multi-touch is supported by default in Windows Phone 8 apps.

Everything is written in C# and XAML. When I try to press two rectangles at the same time the tap event never gets hit on either of them.

Thank you for any thoughts on this.

XAML of tiles:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="tile11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="103" Margin="10,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Tap="TileClickHandler" Hold="TileHoldHandler" MouseLeftButtonDown="tile11_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="tile11_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Tiles/DEFAULT.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="tile12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="103" Margin="120,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Tap="TileClickHandler" Hold="TileHoldHandler" MouseLeftButtonDown="tile11_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="tile11_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Tiles/DEFAULT.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="tile14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="103" Margin="340,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Tap="TileClickHandler" Hold="TileHoldHandler" MouseLeftButtonDown="tile11_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="tile11_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/Tiles/DEFAULT.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
```

One tap handler for all three:

```
private void TileClickHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsRecordingActive)
            {
                StopRecording();
                IsRecordingActive = false;
                ManageTileState(ActiveRecordingTile, Constants.TileStates.HAS_SOUND);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle tile = (System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)sender;
                if (DoesTileHaveSound(tile))
                {
                    Thread soundThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(PlaySound));
                    soundThread.Start(tile.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Without your code, it's difficult to be sure. Have you read through the docs and examples about handling multi touch? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with code.

Comment: From the docs I linked to: "The simplest way to enable touch input in your Windows Phone app is to use mouse events. Mouse events are limited to single-finger gestures such as tap and double tap, and they don't support velocity-based gestures."

Comment: Yeah, i know that but I am looking for a way to enable multitouch.

Comment: The page I linked to has guidance.

Comment: Thanks, I took an advantage of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to come up with my own MultiTouch logic. Meaning that I was using touch detection - and I keep track of what has been touched in each frame. When the element gets touch free I decide what action to take.